# Failed to resolve module specifier "node-fetch". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Hi so I have this piece of code

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

let fetchInfo;
let searchButton = document.getElementById('search-button');
let userInput = document.getElementById('search-username');
let profilePicture = document.getElementById('profile-picture');
let userName = document.getElementById('username');


searchButton.addEventListener('click', fetchUser)

async function fetchUser() {
    fetchInfo = fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${userInput.value}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => data)
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
    
    let userInfo = await fetchInfo;

    userName.innerHTML = `${userInfo['login']}`;
    profilePicture.setAttribute('src', `${userInfo['avatar_url']}`);
}
```

So as you can see by my code Im just fetching a github user and getting some info and that info I am reflecting it on my web page the thing is my **script.js** file has a **package.json** and has a **"type": "module"** so the fetch library can work properly.

**THE PROBLEM**
So as you already guess when my page loads [I get this error in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faJEM.png) so I added to the script tag the attribute type="module" and that fixed the problem but now I'm getting the ***Failed to resolve module specifier "node-fetch". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".*** error

Comment: why are you importing `node-fetch` in the browser? remove `import fetch from 'node-fetch';`

Comment: Im new in the dom I didnt knew, thanks that worked for me